# How can you simulate capacitor behavior in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

According to hyperphysics.edu it says that the voltage on a Capacitor can be expressed as [Vo(1-exp(-t/RC))](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html).

I would like to have a way of applying this build up behavior to a signal, but don't quite know how to do so.

In matlab, if I do something like this:

```
t = 0:0.0001:0.05-0.0001;
tau = 0.005;
c = 1-exp(-t/tau);
s = zeros(1,1000);
s(201:600) = ones(1,400);
```

c looks like what I expect a capacitor charging up to look like. s is ideally what the input voltage would look like if you switch on and off the power. What I would like is to be able to apply that C pattern. I'm not sure
what the mathematical way to do that is. I would think that this is the kind of think you would use convolution on, so I tried

```
o = conv(s,c(500:-1:1));
```

However, plotting that shows the rising action as a straight linear ascent, which doesn't look right, so I think there's something else I need to do.

What kind of operation or method needs to be applied to simulate how a capacitor would act on some input voltage signal, if you have the RC constant?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to be plotting c versus t.  With your command you are plotting 201 points of c at 0 and 299 points of c at 1.

Try

```
    plot(t,c)
```

and you should see an exponential decay.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor term should include only the exponent and the convolution already flips the second vector, so there is no need to flip it again.

dt=0.0001;

t = 0:dt:0.05-dt;

tau = 0.005;

c = dt/tau*exp(-t/tau);

s = zeros(1,1000);

s(201:800) = 1;

o = conv(s,c);

tt=(0:(length(o)-1))*dt;

figure;plot(tt,o)